# Concatenating 2 chr columns if the content of col2 is not in col1

Tags: r, tidyverse

Consider the following table:

```
library(tidyverse)
tdf <- tibble(
  col1 = c(
    "album L. abietis (Wiesb.) Abrom.",
    "abortivum (L.) Swartz abortivum",
    "acanthoclada DC."
  ),
  col2 = c(
    "abietis (Wiesb.) Abrom.",
    "abortivum",
    "acetoselloides (Balansa) Nijs"
  )
)

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# col1                               col2                         
# <chr>                              <chr>                        
# 1 album L. abietis (Wiesb.) Abrom. abietis (Wiesb.) Abrom.      
# 2 abortivum (L.) Swartz abortivum  abortivum                    
# 3 acanthoclada DC.                 acetoselloides (Balansa) Nijs
```

I would like to concatenate `col1` and `col2` if the content of `col2` is not in `col1`.
I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
tdf %>% 
  mutate(col3 = if_else(
    col1 %>% str_detect(col2),
    col1,
    paste(col1, col2)
  ))

# str_detect(tdf$col1, tdf$col2)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

The expected output for `col3` is as follows:

```
col3
<chr>
1 album L. abietis (Wiesb.) Abrom.
2 abortivum (L.) Swartz abortivum
3 acanthoclada DC. acetoselloides (Balansa) Nijs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `str_detect()` with the pattern observing standard collation rules.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

tdf %>%
  mutate(col3 = if_else(str_detect(string = col1, pattern = coll(col2)), col1, str_c(col1, col2, sep = " ")))


# A tibble: 3 x 3
  col1                             col2                          col3                                         
  <chr>                            <chr>                         <chr>                                        
1 album L. abietis (Wiesb.) Abrom. abietis (Wiesb.) Abrom.       album L. abietis (Wiesb.) Abrom.             
2 abortivum (L.) Swartz abortivum  abortivum                     abortivum (L.) Swartz abortivum              
3 acanthoclada DC.                 acetoselloides (Balansa) Nijs acanthoclada DC. acetoselloides (Balansa) Nijs
```

Answer (score -2):

you can try this but i am not sure if it satisfies other condition,

```
tdf %>% 
  mutate(col3 = if_else(
    col1 %in% col2,
    col1,
    paste(col1, col2)
  ))
```

Comment: This will not work because the `%in%` operator checks for an exact match, not if a part of a string is contained in a different character string.